# Smart way to end a subroutine if file doesnt exist in cwd

Tags: python

I am trying to open file "data.txt" in the cwd and readthe lines,is there a oneliner(or close ) to exit the subroutine if the file doesnt exist..i know there are ways like using os.path.exists and try/except IO error but am interested in one-liner or the smartest way

```
def readfile ():
    f = open('data.txt')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and a [conditional expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
import os.path as opath

def readlines(path):
    return open(path).readlines() if opath.exists(path) else []
```

And if you're into lazy evaluation (it will only read as many lines as the caller consumes), combine it with a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
import os.path as opath

def readlines(path):
    try:
        return (l for l in open(path)) if opath.exists(path) else ()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return ()
```

Comment: This has a race condition: calling `exists` will only tell you that the file existed at one point.  There's no guarantee that it'll still be there when you call `open(path).readlines()`, much less later when the genexp is iterated.  So you'll have to be prepared to catch the exception anyway..

Answer (score 7):

you can use `with` open

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

The with statement will automatically close the file after the nested block of code. The advantage of using a with statement is that it is guaranteed to close the file no matter how the nested block exits. If an exception occurs before the end of the block, it will close the file before the exception is caught by an outer exception handler.

If the nested block were to contain a return statement, or a continue or break statement, the with statement would automatically close the file in those cases, too.

Comment: my question to check if the file actually exists and exit the subroutine,does with do that?